# Should I check for the class before adding or removing it in prototype?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I have a line of code in JavaScript, using prototype, that is run several times per second. This line of code, depending on the state of some variables, would ensure that certain element has or has not a class.

My question is, should I blindly add or remove the class or should I check for it first? Should I have this code:

```
if (!element.hasClassName("overtime")) {
  element.addClassName("overtime");
}
if (element2.hasClassName("overtime")) {
  element2.removeClassName("overtime");
}
```

or is it fine to just have:

```
element.addClassName("overtime");
element2.removeClassName("overtime");
```

My reasoning is that adding and removing may be more expensive methods that even though the change happens super fast, may modify the DOM, leading to flakiness or exacerbate a memory leak or something like that.

Comment: May I ask why you have this function running several times per second? Why not just change the classes when one of the variables is changed?

Comment: Because it's not really a variable that changed. It's something like if (new Date() - start_time > too_long) { ... }. I would have to create another state variable, which I'd like to avoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the second one.

By checking prototype code you can see that:

- addClassName already checks for existence
- both hasClassName and removeClassName uses one RegExp to do the search or replacement so there is no benefit there either

Code:

```
  hasClassName: function(element, className) {
    if (!(element = $(element))) return;
    var elementClassName = element.className;
    return (elementClassName.length > 0 && (elementClassName == className ||
      new RegExp("(^|\\s)" + className + "(\\s|$)").test(elementClassName)));
  },

  addClassName: function(element, className) {
    if (!(element = $(element))) return;
    if (!Element.hasClassName(element, className))
      element.className += (element.className ? ' ' : '') + className;
    return element;
  },

  removeClassName: function(element, className) {
    if (!(element = $(element))) return;
    element.className = element.className.replace(
      new RegExp("(^|\\s+)" + className + "(\\s+|$)"), ' ').strip();
    return element;
  },
```